# Gutenberg Blocks, in the editor the attribute has the same value for each iteration

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

When I iterate multiple times the block in the same page.

I have the same value in each of my blocks (default is 3).
If I changed the second block value of numberPosts to 8, The value will be correct. When Updating, the value will come back to 3, and it will show 3 posts in the frontend (dynamic render).

```
export default function edit(props) {

    const { attributes: { numberPosts }, setAttributes } = props;


return (

  <>
    <NumberControl
      label="Number of Posts"
      value={ numberPosts }
      onChange={ ( value ) => setAttributes( { numberPosts: value } ) }
      isShiftStepEnabled={ true }
      shiftStep={ 1 }
    />
  </>
);
}
```

PHP File:

```
    function test_posts_block_renderer($attributes){
    $query = test_posts_block_get_query($attributes);
    $postStyle = $attributes['postStyle'];
    $postType = $attributes['postType'];
    $numberPosts = $attributes['numberPosts'];
    $classes = ( isset($attributes['className']) ) ? $attributes['className'] : '';


    ob_start();
    if ($postStyle == 'list') {
        test_posts_block_get_list($query, $attributes);
    } else {
        test_posts_block_get_blocks($query, $attributes);
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
}

   function test_posts_block_get_query($attributes) {
$postType = $attributes['postType'];
$numberPosts = $attributes['numberPosts'];
$args = array(
    'post_type' => $postType,
    'posts_per_page' => $numberPosts,
    'post_status'            => array('publish'),
    'order'                  => 'DESC',
    'orderby'                => 'date',
);
return new WP_Query($args);
}

function test_posts_block_get_list($query, $attributes) {

$postType = $attributes['postType'];
$classes = ( isset($attributes['className']) ) ? $attributes['className'] : ''; 
echo '<div class="wp-block-create-block has-list '. $classes .'">';

while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="post-block">
            <hr class="wp-block-separator has-text-color has-background has-gray-background-color has-gray-color is-style-wide">
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <p><?php echo test_posts_block_get_content($attributes); ?></p>
            <br>
        </div>
<?php endwhile;

echo '<hr class="wp-block-separator has-text-color has-background has-gray-background-color has-gray-color is-style-wide">';
echo '</div>';
```

}

Comment: How is `numberPosts` being used in your `save()` function? Or is the block rendered dynamically?

Comment: @S.Walsh I have updated the post, it is rendered dynamically